# WIFI adapter dissappeared suddenly after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, upgrade

this is result of my `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 28:d2:44:38:b7:14
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5500000-b557ffff memory:b5580000-b558ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: e
       bus info: usb@3:10
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 3e:b5:df:7f:62:ad
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.199.96 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

As you can see my AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter is there in the list but when I go to the wifi section, it says no adapter found. It was working just fine on ubuntu 21.04 but after upgrade Ican't get it back to work again!

Also, I have windows 10 running as dual boot. can this be the problem?

Here is the result of `modprobe ath9k`

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Invalid argument
```

Here is the result of `grep ath9k /etc/modprobe.d/*`

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf:options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

And here is the result of `sudo dmesg | grep ath:`:

```
[   18.864091] ath: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
[   18.864097] ath: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
[   18.864098] ath: Unknown symbol freq_reg_info (err -22)
[  516.507570] ath: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz
[  516.507575] ath: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -22)
[  516.507587] ath: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
```

Comment: I guess you mean 22.04 ( year.month ). Always state clearly the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe ath9k` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @Shaheen: if the UEFI part worked, accept the answer. It will show other users that the question is solved

Comment: @chili555 I included the responses

Comment: Please add output of `grep ath9k /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu 21" or "Ubuntu 22". Please specify which version you've upgraded to which.

Comment: There is no upgrade path from 21.04 to 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me five days to fix!!

In  response to `dmesg`, we saw this:

```
[   18.864097] ath: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
[   18.864091] ath: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
```

With the `dkms status` command, I saw that there are unnecessary extra drivers like `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` installed for my WIFI which I have added while attempting to solve this.

I got rid of those with purging:

```
 sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

And then a reboot and voilà, my wifi is working again!

Answer (score 1):

The device should be [supported](http://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:168c-0032-103c-1785) and Windows does not have anything to do with it.

By installing the new version is could be that "Secure Boot" is activated again. Check your UEFI and disable it.

Comment: Checked the UEFI not working

Comment: Did you disable **Secure Boot** ? It prevents drivers to work.

Comment: Yes it is disabled @kanehekili